# python : name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I got title's error with the following code. Does anyone know how to fix this? I already checked the tabs and spaces on the .py file and tried even changing var's names and it was useless. Thanks on advance

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=["jinja2.ext.autoescape"],
    autoescape=True)

class ConsumoHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def load_input(self):
        self.km=float(self.request.get("edKm","edKm"))
        self.consmed=float(self.request.get("edCons","edCons"))
        self.tiempo=float(self.request.get("edTiempo","edTiempo"))
        self.velMed=0
        self.consTot=0

    def post(self):
        self.load_input()
        self.km=str(self.km)
        self.consmed=str(self.consmed)
        self.tiempo=str(self.tiempo)
        velMed=(self.km)/(self.tiempo)
        self.velMed=str(velMed)
        consTot=(self.km)/((self.consmed)*4)
        self.consTot=str(consTot)

        template_values = { 
        'kmToStr':self.km,
        'consmedToStr':self.consmed,
        'tiempoToStr':self.tiempo,
        'velMedToStr':self.velMed,
        'consTotToStr':self.consTot, 
        }

    template_values = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("answer.html")
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values));

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/calcu', ConsumoHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: `self.response.write(template.render(template_values));` is not part of a method so executed when the class is being defined. Perhaps you got your indentations mixed up?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces. Reconfigure your editor to *only* use spaces for indentation, then convert remaining spaces to tabs.

Comment: Question: Why does (self.response.write(template.render(template_values));) contain the trailing semicolon? It is not required unless you wish to have several things evaluated on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is this line:

```
self.response.write(template.render(template_values));
```

It's inside the class definition, but not inside a method (which first parameter is `self`. So `self` is not known here...

You have to indent it to be part of the `post` method:

```
def post(self):
    ...
    template_values = { 
        ...
    }

    template_values = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("answer.html")
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values));
```

Comment: Perfectly answered! He probably meant to do both lines of code from within post(). Maybe update your answer to state that!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Yep, added it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the line `self.response.write(template.render(template_values));` cannot be outside any function here, since there is no `'self'` variable there.

Secondly, and *this is a guess*, based on the fact that you are overwriting the `template_values` variable, you probably wanted your post method to be like (note the last two lines indented and with a variable name changed):

```
def post(self):
    self.load_input()
    self.km=str(self.km)
    self.consmed=str(self.consmed)
    self.tiempo=str(self.tiempo)
    velMed=(self.km)/(self.tiempo)
    self.velMed=str(velMed)
    consTot=(self.km)/((self.consmed)*4)
    self.consTot=str(consTot)

    template_values = { 
    'kmToStr':self.km,
    'consmedToStr':self.consmed,
    'tiempoToStr':self.tiempo,
    'velMedToStr':self.velMed,
    'consTotToStr':self.consTot, 
    }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("answer.html") # Do not overwrite template_values, and use correct indentation
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values));
```